# Container view, Failed use delegate

Tags: ios, swift

i wanna designed slide function.So i use container view in storyboard without any segue.there is  a button in centerView to open or close leftView.but this function is written in container.swift and i don't know how to set delegate..please help me,thanks.(All codes as below)

Container.swift

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController,test {


    var leftViewController: UIViewController? {
        willSet{
            if self.leftViewController != nil {
                if self.leftViewController!.view != nil {
                    self.leftViewController!.view!.removeFromSuperview()
                }
                self.leftViewController!.removeFromParentViewController()
            }
        }

        didSet{

            self.view!.addSubview(self.leftViewController!.view)
            self.addChildViewController(self.leftViewController!)
        }
    }

    var rightViewController: UIViewController? {
        willSet {
            if self.rightViewController != nil {
                if self.rightViewController!.view != nil {
                    self.rightViewController!.view!.removeFromSuperview()
                }
                self.rightViewController!.removeFromParentViewController()
            }
        }

        didSet{

            self.view!.addSubview(self.rightViewController!.view)
            self.addChildViewController(self.rightViewController!)
        }
    }

    var menuShown: Bool = false


    func showMenu() {

        print(__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.rightViewController!.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x + 235, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                self.menuShown = true
        })
    }

    func hideMenu() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.rightViewController!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                self.menuShown = false
        })
    }

    var centerView:CenterViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let CenterNC:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterNC") as! UINavigationController

        let leftVC:LeftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftVC") as! LeftViewController

         centerView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterVC") as! CenterViewController

        self.leftViewController = leftVC
        self.rightViewController = CenterNC


       self.centerView.delegate = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
CenterViewController.swift


import UIKit

protocol test{
    func showMenu()
    func hideMenu()
}

class CenterViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate:test! = nil


    @IBAction func pressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (delegate != nil) {
            delegate.showMenu()
        }
        else{
            print("Error")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[Debug ContainerView.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC8oH.png)

[Debug CenterViewController.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoXzv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use `whatever.delegate = self` but I'm not quite sure what you want to do. (Also `whatever.datasource = self`). I dont know if this works for VCs.

As far as I know it is bad practice to have one `UIViewController` in the storyboard that contains two other VCs.

Rather you should either transition programmatically or with a storyboard segue.

`self.presentViewController(LeftViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)` 
`self.dismissViewController(true, completion: nil)`

View Controllers are automatically removed from memory (look up ARC if your curious) (as long as you don't have variables in the VC to be removed that are (or can be) accessed from another class that wasn't deinitialized - if that's confusing ignore it)

If you want a sliding animation or something like this, it's probably best to find something on GitHub to clone and import into your project. I've made an app with a tab bar that slides between views with some code I found online.

I've been droning but having two VCs in one VC is terrible for memory and in general bad practice. Utilize Custom Segues instead.